# Burninate [element]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

[element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/element):

> In metadata, the term data element is an atomic unit of data that has precise meaning or precise semantics.

… that's not very specific.

For, DOM elements [dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dom) works. For elements in a list, [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list) or [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array) work. Element is too ambiguous.

Comment: @bjb568 Containers have elements, and these are common data structures involved in programming questions.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It seems to be both used for DOM Elements and array elements, which are very different things. [dom], [array], and [list] already exist.

Comment: I notice that we also have [tag:elements] (with an "s") in addition to plain old [tag:element]. Despite their similar names, they aren't synonyms - the [tag wiki for the former](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/elements/info) suggests that it refers to array elements.